# watir webdriver not working Firefox 26

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm unable to use Watir with the latest Firefox 26. I have updated all gems to latest versions, but still facing the issue.

Here's my watir gem list:

```
watir (5.0.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
watir-webdriver-rails (0.0.8)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for help

Comment: What version of selenium-webdriver do you have?

Comment: In local gems I have: selenium-webdriver (2.39.0, 2.31.0)

Comment: Can you give a sample script that fails and what the failure is?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem today. I found Jarmo's reply as helpful. Thank you.

```
gem update selenium-webdriver
```

This fixed the issue with firefox v26.

I didnt have enough points to add  a comment to the existing post or mark it as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest selenium-webdriver. If you're using bundler then issue `bundle update selenium-webdriver`.